# django regroup odd behavior

Tags: django, django-templates

I for whatever reason cannot duplicate this issue locally but on my production server in one of my templates the regroup tag is doing something odd. I'm trying to group all donations that have the same pickup_id and just display how many of them were "missed". For some reason it's showing the same pickup_id more than once in my list.

view

```
missed_routes = Donor.objects.filter(missed='YES').order_by('pickup_date')
```

template

```
{% block content %}
{% regroup missed_routes by pickup_id as missed_pickups %}

<div class="missedColumn">
    <h2>Missed Donations</h2>
    <p>Looks like we have some stragglers…</p>
    <p>These routes have missed donations in them.</p>
    {% for routes in missed_pickups %}

        <p><a href="/reschedule/{{ routes.grouper }}">{{ routes.list.0.route }}</a> - {{ routes.list.0.pickup_date }} ({{ routes.list|length }} missed - {{ routes.list.0.pickup_id }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

resulting html # the 600 is the pickup_id

```
        <p><a href="/reschedule/600">Syosset</a> - Sept. 14, 2012 (1 missed - 600</p>


        <p><a href="/reschedule/423">Huntington Station</a> - Sept. 14, 2012 (1 missed - 423</p>


        <p><a href="/reschedule/600">Syosset</a> - Sept. 14, 2012 (2 missed - 600</p>
```

When iterating over each donor in a pickup html output

```
        <p><a href="/reschedule/600">Syosset</a> - Sept. 14, 2012 (1 missed - 600
        <ul>

            <li>134170</li>

        </ul>
        </p>


        <p><a href="/reschedule/423">Huntington Station</a> - Sept. 14, 2012 (1 missed - 423
        <ul>

            <li>134938</li>

        </ul>
        </p>


        <p><a href="/reschedule/600">Syosset</a> - Sept. 14, 2012 (2 missed - 600
        <ul>

            <li>134174</li>

            <li>133151</li>

        </ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible there is some subtle difference between two pickup_ids, such as a space? Maybe you can show the relevant HTML on the page?

Comment: it's an IntegerField so they're shoulden't be any whitespace. The pickup_id is generated automatically once one is created and a donor is then assigned a pickup_id.

Comment: Could you show the resulting HTML?

Comment: html is posted in the OP

Comment: Hmmm, interesting that 2 were in one group and only 1 in the other. Could you have it show the primary key of each individual Donor in each group, using a for loop like `for donor in routes.list`? That would confirm whether there's one Donor ending up in two groups or three Donors that get split

Comment: @DavidRobinson here you go.I put it in OP again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that Django's regroup depends on the list being ordered by the attribute you're regrouping by. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup):

> Note that {% regroup %} does not order its input! Our example relies on the fact that the cities list was ordered by country in the first place. If the cities list did not order its members by country, the regrouping would naively display more than one group for a single country

Thus, change:

```
missed_routes = Donor.objects.filter(missed='YES').order_by('pickup_date')
```

to

```
missed_routes = Donor.objects.filter(missed='YES').order_by('pickup_id')
```

Comment: that did it! I feel so stupid for not catching that. Thank you so much. However, how can I order my output so that the results still sort in order of pickup_date?

Comment: No worries, it took me a few minutes to catch too (but it's good to hit the docs in these cases). However, you can't have them both grouped by pickup_id and sorted by date- those two orders can conflict). Do you mean sorted by date *within* each group?

Comment: (In that case, you would do `.order_by('pickup_id', 'pickup_date')`)

Comment: sorry, yes that's what I mean. I want to sort it so that each grouped date is in order.

Comment: One last thing- what kind of field is `missed`? If it's only "YES" and "NO", shouldn't you make it a BooleanField rather than a CharField?

Comment: Its a NullBooleanField actually. The purpose of this field has changed a few times throughout the building of this project. My code could use a lot of cleaning up all over the place since it's only a side consulting project.